# convert function with ...rest to React class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I would like convert my classic function using `{component: Component, ...rest}` on params to React class :

```
const AdminLayout = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
  // ...
};
```

I don't know how i can setting **component** and **...rest** to my constructor.

Similare question : what is the best practice on react : function or class ?

Anyone can help me ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 0):

You can just go with the plain old way to construct a react component, i.e,

```
class AdminLayout extends Component {
 // ..
}
```

and all the properties `...rest` will be in the `this.props` object.

Comment: Hi aditya :) I've already test it, but i don't know how i can create my params with **component: Component** and **...rest**. Ex. : **this.rest = ...rest** in my constructor ?

Comment: so what exactly is your question, do you want to make the component using class constructor or using the react's functional components?

Comment: I would like using react's functional components, but i need to get the params in constructor, no ?

Comment: By params you mean the props, right? If so, you can just pass the props as,:

`const AdminLayout = (props) =>  {}`

Comment: you can access any prop by going, `props.name` if name was a passed prop